# Shell Conditional Issues

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have searched and tried numerous solutions but being new to shell I am lost. I am setting a variable in one .sh, calling a second, then trying to act on whether it is true or not.

```
testA.sh
#!/bin/sh

DB=1
. testB.sh
```

------------------------------------

```
testB.sh

if ${DB}==1; then
echo "DB is on"
fi
```

I get 1==1 command not found.

Comment: What does perl have to do with this? I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to test whether or not a variable is set, the standard way is:

```
if test "${DB+set}" = set; then
  # here, $DB is set
fi
```

If you want to check that it is set to a particular string value, use:

```
if test "$DB" = value; ...
```

if you want to check for a particular integer value:

```
if test "$DB" -eq 4; ...
```

The last form will generate an error message if DB is a string value that does not look like an integer.

Answer (score 5):

should be:

```
if [[ "$DB" = "1"]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ $DB -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way you do [equality testing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html) in Bash...

Answer (score 0):

```
testB.sh

if test ${DB} == 1; then
echo "DB is on"
fi
```